# Map reduce without using input file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to do map reduce job without input file.  Instead, I am having a string itself as input.  The string is as follows :

```
1,aaa,23000
2,bbb,30000
3,ccc,40000
```

Instead of FileInputFormat class what should I use?  can anyone tell me how the program should be, or Is there any example with this use case?  If so, kindly share me the link.

Thank you.

Comment: MapReduce is used to deal with large amounts of data and perform batch processing. I doubt if what you're trying to do is even possible.

Comment: Why can't that _string_ go in a file?

Comment: philantrovert, my task is to get string data in real time and store in hdfs.  In such case, I cant read data every time from a file.  Instead, I am getting the string content itself in my java program.